# Installing multiple node modules with batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will install node modules from, and in, different directories.  My problem is that the script is navigating to the foo directory and executing npm install but then it won't execute the other two do() commands.

```
do(
    cd foo
    npm install
)

do(
    cd ../bar
    npm install
)

do(
    cd ../again
    bower install
)
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the following in a .bat file

```
call Install_Node_Components_Site.bat

call Install_Bower_Components.bat

call Install_Node_Components_Test.bat
```

The Install_Node_Components_Site.bat file is very basic and looks like this.

```
cd foo
npm install
```

The foo directory has the packages.json file so my thinking is that I can just call npm install like I normally would from the command line.

Comment: Is npm a Batch file: `npm.bat`? If so, you need to execute it via call command: `call npm install`. The same point apply to `bower`

Comment: Ok.  So your suggestion worked.  If you want to put that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If npm is a Batch file: `npm.bat`, it requires to be executed via `call` command this way:

```
do(
    cd foo
    call npm install
)
```

The same point apply for `bower` command.